# Jasny SSO: Session has expired. Client must attach with new token

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I have 3 brokers using the demo sample code. Two of this brokers run on local virtual hosts. The third runs on a remote server with HTTPS, as the SSO server.

The local brokers works properly (info, login, logout). The remote broker return the error "Session has expired. Client must attach with new token".

In all cases, the cache files are created, named as SSO-(brokerId)-(token).php.cache and all have the same content.

The problem occurs in Server/GlobalSession.php, method resume(). Session id is provided ans session started, but $_SESSION is empty and the throws the Exception.

Any help?
Thanks

=== Remote broker: error ===

```
{"timestamp":"1707378089","channel":"SSO","level":"DEBUG","level_value":100,"message":"Validating","context":{"broker":"Julius","token":"65sueedke8w0sgcoks4gskoksowco4oocgocc0o4wwsw8so0k8","code":"5c00kvp0wzk00kcs048g4ocwc8k84ssg0ckw0404oosgwo8kww","checksum":"1epsadzc5vz4gg8ogkwo8wscockokgwos4kc08k0kgwkowsok4"},"backtrace":{"file":"/web/htdocs/test.echosistemi.it/home/sso/src/Server/Server.php","line":109,"class":"Jasny\\SSO\\Server\\Server","function":"startBrokerSession"},"pid":211}

{"timestamp":"1707378089","channel":"SSO","level":"DEBUG","level_value":100,"message":"Resuming","context":{"session":"ucgu13302vc3ac9av89qr5f7fb"},"backtrace":{"file":"/web/htdocs/test.echosistemi.it/home/sso/src/Server/Server.php","line":114,"class":"Jasny\\SSO\\Server\\Server","function":"startBrokerSession"},"pid":211}
```

=== Local broker: success ===

```
{"timestamp":"1707378221","channel":"SSO","level":"DEBUG","level_value":100,"message":"Validating","context":{"broker":"Greg","token":"4wjlaezl8fi8cocgk8w0sgscoos4cog804w4c4o04o8cog4s8s","code":"5uhlf5uwus4c40kw8w0k8sko40wkww04w4kgk0c4k0sg848c4s","checksum":"2zgrk1l3qqucc4k884ccs4scwcswskcw84kgcoksk4owkc408g"},"backtrace":{"file":"/web/htdocs/test.echosistemi.it/home/sso/src/Server/Server.php","line":109,"class":"Jasny\\SSO\\Server\\Server","function":"startBrokerSession"},"pid":247}

{"timestamp":"1707378221","channel":"SSO","level":"DEBUG","level_value":100,"message":"Resuming","context":{"session":"ucgu13302vc3ac9av89qr5f7fb"},"backtrace":{"file":"/web/htdocs/test.echosistemi.it/home/sso/src/Server/Server.php","line":114,"class":"Jasny\\SSO\\Server\\Server","function":"startBrokerSession"},"pid":247}

{"timestamp":"1707378221","channel":"SSO","level":"DEBUG","level_value":100,"message":"Resumed","context":{"session":"ucgu13302vc3ac9av89qr5f7fb"},"backtrace":{"file":"/web/htdocs/test.echosistemi.it/home/sso/src/Server/Server.php","line":118,"class":"Jasny\\SSO\\Server\\Server","function":"startBrokerSession"},"pid":247}

{"timestamp":"1707378221","channel":"SSO","level":"DEBUG","level_value":100,"message":"Broker request with session","context":{"broker":"Greg","token":"4wjlaezl8fi8cocgk8w0sgscoos4cog804w4c4o04o8cog4s8s","session":"ucgu13302vc3ac9av89qr5f7fb"},"backtrace":{"file":"/web/htdocs/test.echosistemi.it/home/sso/src/Server/Server.php","line":120,"class":"Jasny\\SSO\\Server\\Server","function":"startBrokerSession"},"pid":247}
```

=== SSO-Greg-4wjlaezl8fi8cocgk8w0sgscoos4cog804w4c4o04o8cog4s8s.php.cache ===

9223372036854775807
s:26:"ucgu13302vc3ac9av89qr5f7fb";

=== SSO-Julius-65sueedke8w0sgcoks4gskoksowco4oocgocc0o4wwsw8so0k8.php.cache ===

9223372036854775807
s:26:"ucgu13302vc3ac9av89qr5f7fb";

I'm expecting the remote broker to resume th session properly as it happens with local brokers